# jQuery change URL of form submit

Tags: jquery

I want to change the URL the form is submitted to upon click as seen below. Below is what I have tried but it does not work.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="contactsForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="widget-content">

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">  &nbsp;
        <span class="icon-folder-open icon-large"></span>
        Move To <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        {% for x,y in actionsForm.fields.move_to.choices %}
        <li><a class="move_to" id="{{ x }}" href="#">{{ y }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".move_to").on("click", function () {
            $('#contactsFrom').attr('action', "/test1");
            $("#contactsFrom").submit();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: BTW. You have a typo in your ID: #contactsFrom - I take it it's meant to be #contactsForm

Comment: yes well spotted. thanks

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$(".move_to").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#contactsForm').attr('action', "/test1").submit();
});
```

Moving the order in which you use `.preventDefault()` might fix your issue. You also didn't use `function(e)` so `e.preventDefault();` wasn't working.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/TfTwe/1/ - first of all, click the 'Check action attribute.' link. You'll get an alert saying `undefined`. Then click 'Set action attribute.' and click 'Check action attribute.' again. You'll see that the form's action attribute has been correctly set to `/test1`.

Comment: I see, 'e' is now passed but it now appears to not run at all, no errors. is preventDefault just stopping everything?

Comment: I see, sorry it was a type o

Answer (score 2):

Send the data from the form:

```php
$("#change_section_type").live "change", ->
url = $(this).attr("data-url")
postData = $(this).parents("#contract_setting_form").serializeArray()
$.ajax
  type: "PUT"
  url: url
  dataType: "script"
  data: postData
```