# How to submit a form in two different place clicking to two submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form in html,inside this form I have a input-type-file and two input-type-submit button.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="input_file">

    <input type="submit" value="Goto This Page">
    <input type="submit" value="Goto That Page">
</form>
```

We know a form can submit whole form in a single page(action).But I need to submit the form in two different place by clicking two different button.

Thank You,

Comment: You can do this by ajax not needed two submit button

Comment: you can change action of form before submit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966383/jquery-change-url-of-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="input_file">

    <input type="submit" value="Goto This Page" name="submit1">
    <input type="submit" value="Goto That Page" name="submit2">
    </form>
    <?php
          if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
           {
                header("location:first_page.php");
           }
          if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
          {
                header("location:second_page.php");
          }

   ?>


</body>
</html>
```